# Something wrong with Sigmoid curve for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sigmoid

I'm trying to use logistic regression on the popularity of hits songs on Spotify from 2010-2019 based on their durations and durability, whose data are collected from a .csv file. Basically, since the popularity values of each song are numerical, I have converted each of them to binary numbers "0" to "1". If the popularity value of a hit song is less than 70, I will replace its current value to 0, and vice versa if its value is more than 70. For some reason, as the rest of my code is pretty standard in creating a sigmoid function, the end result is a straight line instead of a sigmoid curve.

```
 %matplotlib inline
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 import pandas as pd

 df = pd.read_csv('top10s [SubtitleTools.com] (2).csv')

 BPM = df.bpm
 BPM = np.array(BPM)
 Energy = df.nrgy
 Energy = np.array(Energy)
 Dance = df.dnce
 Dance = np.array(Dance)
 dB = df.dB
 dB = np.array(dB)
 Live = df.live
 Live = np.array(Live)
 Valence = df.val
 Valence = np.array(Valence)
 Acous = df.acous
 Acous = np.array(Acous)
 Speech = df.spch
 Speech = np.array(Speech)

 df.loc[df['popu'] <= 70, 'popu'] = 0

 df.loc[df['popu'] > 70, 'popu'] = 1

 def Logistic_Regression(X, y, iterations, alpha):
   ones = np.ones((X.shape[0], ))
   X = np.vstack((ones, X))
   X = X.T
   b = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

   for i in range(iterations):
     z = np.dot(X, b)
     p_hat = sigmoid(z)
     gradient = np.dot(X.T, (y - p_hat))
     b = b + alpha * gradient
     if (i % 1000 == 0):
       print('LL, i ', log_likelihood(X, y, b), i)
   return b

 def sigmoid(z):
   return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))

 def log_likelihood(X, y, b):
   z = np.dot(X, b)
   LL = np.sum(y*z - np.log(1 + np.exp(z)))
   return LL

 def LR1():
   Dur = df.dur
   Dur = np.array(Dur)
   Pop = df.popu

   Pop = [int(i) for i in Pop]; Pop = np.array(Pop)


   plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
   colormap = np.array(['r', 'b'])
   plt.scatter(Dur, Pop, c = colormap[Pop], alpha = .4)
   b = Logistic_Regression(Dur, Pop, iterations = 8000, alpha = 0.00005)
   print('Done')

   p_hat = sigmoid(np.dot(Dur, b[1]) + b[0])
   idxDur = np.argsort(Dur)
   plt.plot(Dur[idxDur], p_hat[idxDur])
   plt.show()

 LR1()

 df
```

[image: Current graph]

[image: CSV File]

Comment: since your sigmoid is coming out as either ~0 or ~1  , the argument thereto (np.dot(Dur, b[1]) + b[0]) must be  large positive or negative values. Maybe you've missed a normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Your logreg params arent coming out correctly, thus something is wrong in your gradient descent.

If I do

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression    
df = pd.DataFrame({'popu':[0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0],'dur'[217,283,200,295,221,176,206,260,217,213]})
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(Dur.reshape([10,1]),Pop.reshape([10,1]))
print(logreg.coef_)
print(logreg.intercept_)
```

I get [0.86473507, -189.79655798]

whereas your params (b) come out [0.012136874150412973 -0.2430389407767768] for this data.

Plot of your vs scikit logregs [here](http://www.imagebam.com/image/ba91ab1329464810)